# NestJS cannot verify argument is available in current context/Mongoose Inject Model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, nestjs

I followed the MongoDB tutorial on the nestjs website but am unable to replicate it in my own project, I have cloned the nextjs repo and verified that the mongo sample supplied there runs fine.

This is what I currently have (minified):

app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost/nest')
  ],
  modules: [
    CampaignModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {}
}
```

campaign.module.ts

```
@Module(
  {
    modules: [SharedModule],
    controllers: [CampaignController],
    components: [CampaignService],
    imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: 'Campaign', schema: campaignSchema}])]
  })
export class CampaignModule {}
```

campaign.service.ts

```
@Component()
export class CampaignService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(campaignSchema) private readonly campaignModel: Model<CampaignInterface>) {}
}
```

this builds fine as expected but when I run it i get this error:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CampaignService (?). Please verify whether [0] argument is available in the current context.
```

So because in my app.module.ts I have the campaign module in the modules section (how i have had it so far working fine prior to mongodb) I moved it into the imports sections with the MongooseModule now it will build and run fine, but the routes inside the controller for campaign.controller.ts do not register at all, they just return 404's. This is weird because the example in the nestjs repo have the CatsModule inside the imports with the MongooseModule and it works.

Any tips here would be appreciated. this is my schema and interface for the campaign object as well:

```
export interface CampaignInterface extends Document, Campaign {
}

export const campaignSchema: any = new mongoose.Schema({
  campaignId: String
});
```

**EDIT 1**
I moved all my modules into the import section of my app.module.ts file as before I tried it with CampaignModule in imports and all the others in modules: []. It now fails right away when served with the same error and no routes are registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out what is going on,

It seems that if you have both a modules: [] and imports: [] inside your @Module decorator the modules: [] takes over and completely ignores the imports: []. So in my campaign.module.ts file I moved the SharedModule from modules: [] into imports: [] after the MongooseModules.forFeature import. It now works and write to mongo!